# HTML concatenate div containers

Tags: html, class

In most HTML files I've been looking in to learn HTML I can find lots of code written like this:

```
<div class="lvl1">
    <div class="lvl2">
        <div class="lvl3">
            <a>my content</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if from a "my content" point of view this was strictly equivalent to following code:

```
<div class="lvl1 lvl2 lvl3">
    <a>my content</a>
</div>
```

Comment: May i know,What do you want from youe code?

Comment: I've got some ready made templates, only trying to understand in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "div" with three differents CSS class is not the same as three imbricated divs.

The example code is trivial, and it's clearly nonsense to imbricate three divs if only "lvl3" contains some html. But if all the divs contains html, trying to represent this with one div is just impossible.

Comment: In fact i've seen code with multi div levels and content only in the last level. My question makes sense only for those cases yes.

Comment: if some javascript adds content to the divs, or if the design of the site (visually) needs three box (with CSS), it's correct. Otherwise, it's poorly written html.


I see also the use of "class" (and not "id"). If those class are used more than one time in the code, ok. But if only one element has this class name, it must be an id and not a class.

Answer (score 1):

No. `div` is a block element. Hence, without tweaking the CSS, the first has three blocks. The last one.